# How does ruby group, order and select in a single statement

Tags: ruby

```
arr = [{name: 'one'}, {name: 'two'}, {name: 'one'}, {name: 'three'}]
```

How can I get an array of string from it, ["one", "two", "three"]. If each item in arr is considered a row, what I want is a simple ruby way of doing what following sql statement does:

```
select name from test group by name order by count(*) desc
```

This is the way I do in Rails currently, but I think that is too much coding.

```
tags_hash = arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h,t| h[t.name]+=1; h}
descending = -1
tags_array = tags_hash.sort_by {|k,v| v * descending}
@tags = tags_array.collect {|item| item[0]}
```

Comment: You can start by reading about ruby's `group_by` method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Comment: @sawa It is just a way of express what I want. That works in sqlite3

Comment: @sawa: isn't it obvious?

Comment: @sawa I have updated my question, sorry about the misunderstanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.group_by { |i| i[:name] }.sort_by { |name, items| items.length }.reverse.map(&:first)
```

Group by groups the elements by name:

```
arr.group_by { |i| i[:name] }
# => {"one"=>[{:name=>"one"}, {:name=>"one"}], "two"=>[{:name=>"two"}], "three"=>[{:name=>"three"}]}
```

Sort by orders them by the number of found items in each, reverse makes it descending order.

The `map` extracts the actual name of each group.

```
# => ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Comment: Simple and works, thanks. I have read about group_by and sort_by, just didn't find out the other two methods

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `["one", "two", "three"]` sorted from that array you can write something like this:

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
arr.map{|i| i[:name]}.each { |name| counts[name] += 1 }
counts.sort{|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]}.map(&:first)
```

Comment: This doesn't implement all requirements

Comment: I missed the sorting requirement, now it should be ok :-)